# how to initialize a vector of registers in verilog?

Tags: verilog, register

I want to initialize the following 16-bit registers in my module.

```
reg [15:0] coefficient[4:0];
```

I used concatenation operator to do this:

```
reg [15:0] coefficient[4:0] = {16'd26, 16'd270, 16'd734, 16'd21, 16'd90};
```

but I simulate it with ISE, I receive this error:

```
constant value of constant expression must be used for initialization
```

how can I fix it??

EDIT: because `initial` is not synthesizable, I didn't use that. is there another way??

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to suggest you use System Verilog but I don't think ISE supports that. (I went through the file settings and I could not find it).

You then have to use an initial statement:

```
initial
begin
   coefficient[0] = 16'd26;
   coefficient[1] = 16'd270;
   ...
end
```

Comment: I don't want to use initial since it is not synthesizable. I have to use Verilog. because it is a homework!

Comment: @FatemehKarimi, why do you think this use of `initial` is not synthesizable?

Comment: @ThePhoton I read it on internet, that initial is not synthesizable.

Comment: @FatemehKarimi, using `initial` to initialize registers or memories is absolutely synthesizable. Using `initial` to launch a sequence of transitions (like is often done in a testbench) is not synthesizable.

Comment: @ThePhoton then the problem is done! you can write an answer and I will accept it

Comment: @ThePhoton AIUI whether initial is synthisiable depends on the particular synthisis tool.

Comment: @PeterGreen, whether `always @(posedge clk)` is synthesizable depends on the particular synthesis tool too.

Comment: That may be true in a tautalogical sense but in a practical sense AIUI while some synthsis tools will grab initial valies from inital blocks others just ignore them completely.

Comment: In some cases, you can actually do quite a bit of calculation in initial blocks, such as computing contents of lookup tables. Even floating point and trig functions are usually fair game. So long as the result is constant at synthesis time, you're probably good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an explicit value at reset. This is compatible with both ASIC and FPGA implementation. Additionally, it allows for a clean reset if needed as there is no guarantee otherwise that coefficient would return to its first state. For example:

```
always @(negedge nRESET) begin
    coefficient[0] <= 16'd26;
    coefficient[1] <= 16'd270;
    ...
end
```

You may also want to look at [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/226959/is-it-right-to-initialize-a-reg-in-verilog-and-apply-condition-with-initial-valu) old question.

Comment: If coefficient ends up being a constant, then doing this alone will result in a whole lot of logic that could have been optimized out. However, this is definitely a good idea in combination with an initial block.

Comment: @alex.forencich The problem, I believe (although could be wrong), is that using the initial block leaves it to the synthesis tool to decide at what stage "coefficient" is set. If you have a warm reset, for example, what value does "coefficient" take compared to a power up reset? Using a defined reset value is the safest way, and the only way for an ASIC.