# SystemVerilog - Enforcing prevention of inline initialization of logic/reg elements used as flip-flops

Tags: flipflop, system-verilog, asic, verilator, yosys

Given a SystemVerilog design modeling an ASIC, how can I enforce [the rule](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/226959/is-it-right-to-initialize-a-reg-in-verilog-and-apply-condition-with-initial-valu) that all logic/reg elements that are used in flip-flops should not be initialized to a certain value?  Is there a directive that I can use in my code that would prevent this?

Here's an example:

```
module asic (...);
    logic a;    // this is fine
    // logic a = 1;    // but this is not fine

    reg b = 1;  // this is fine since it is not a flip-flop

    always @(posedge clk, posedge rst)
    if (rst)
        a <= 0;
    else if (b)
        a <= ~a;
endmodule
```

I think a check like this would be really helpful in ensuring that all registers in the ASIC design have a reset.  The tools I use are Verilator (for linting and simulation) and Yosys (for synthesis), but I haven't been able to find a related option in their documentation.

Comment: I don't know System Verilog, but can you use logic a = X; ?

Comment: If by 'X' you mean the 'X'/unknown value, what I'm trying to achieve is the prevention of any use of logic initialization of the form 'logic NAME = VALUE'.

Comment: OK, then just verify that all flip flop outputs are X before you assert reset. Or grep the source for "logic .* = [01]"

Comment: I'm actually doing this for now until support is added for the feature.  I'll make sure to update this post once I find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Inline initialization is not good, even for the `b` signal. A commercial tool I use for ASIC synthesis ignores those initializations and throws warnings.

If `b` is a constant, the below would be better (still not ideal).

```
logic b;
assign b = 1;
```

I experienced failures in [formal equivalence checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_equivalence_checking) (RTL vs. synthesis netlist) as well, so I avoid inline initializations in design.

Comment: I'm thinking you can't tell me, but could you tell me which tool you were using so I could do some research into how it checks for those initializations?  I can't use it myself since I have to use open-source tools since the software I wrote that uses it is used in academia.

Comment: @norandomtechie It was Synopsys Design Compiler.

Comment: Is Synopsys Design Compiler accepting assignment of logic inside initial block to synthesis ???

Comment: @MituRaj [No](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48793397).